# React-Native Map array of Objects issues

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a list from my `firebase-firestore` and add them to favourites. However when I console.log() what I am getting back I am supposed to get the following:

```
Array [
      Object {},
      Object {}
]
```

Maybe the way I am retrieving the data and adding it is wrong or the way I am trying to get the `Array` from my `Content` code is wrong. Bascially I am getting the data in my Reducer and retrieving it from my `Content` Component.

This is my Reducer:

```
import { TOGGLE_FAVOURITE } from '../actions/favs'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const initialState = {
    favourites: [],
}
const FavReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_FAVOURITE:
            let fav = []
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection('Posts')
                .where('postId', '==', action.placeId)
                .get()
                .then(snapshots => {
                    snapshots.docs.forEach(doc => {
                        fav.push(JSON.stringify(doc.data()))
                    })
                })
                console.log(fav)
                // I am getting this when I console Log
                // Array [
                //     Object {
                //       "id": "VpcupAWap8RRIbLSt0ZuleCh2C22",
                //       "image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/images%2FK1597089892681.jpg",
                //       "method": Array [
                //         Object {
                //           "id": 1597089887299,
                //           "features": "Lovely tiny house with its own 3 piece bathroom",
                //         },
                //       ],
                //       "name": "Table"
                // ]
            return { ...state, favourites: state.favourites.concat(fav) }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default FavReducer
```

My Content Component Code:

```
const Content = (props) => {
    const currenItemIsFavorite = useSelector(state => state.item.favourites);
    const get = currenItemIsFavorite.map(fav => fav)

    console.log(get)
    // I am getting this when I console Log

    // Array [
    //     Object {},
    //     Object {}
    // ]
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.background}>
            <Text>{console.log(get)}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

export default Content
```

[image]

Please can someone help me I am new to firebase and React-Native. Any help would be much appriciated!!!!!

This is the document I am working with

Comment: Please edit the question to show the document you're working with.  The output will make more sense when we're able to see what's actually in that document.  If you have a different expectation for what should be printed in the log, please explain that in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with the firebase document

Comment: The output makes sense.  You have an array of document objects, which is what you coded.  Were you expecting something different?

Comment: However I can't access the objects contents. It is not letting me for example map it out into the `Content` component it is just showing an empty array. Is may way of adding into favourites array correct?